# in windows, launch tasks when a file/directory is modified

Tags: monitoring, windows-task-scheduler

In linux/mac, for monitoring the changes in a file or directory, I can use tools like [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/), this launch tasks when a file is modified ?

exist a similar tool for windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/277450/how-to-trigger-a-task-at-any-change-on-a-folder-with-windows-server-task-schedul

Don't think its possible with Task Scheduler, but Powershell should be able to do it (Assuming your running a version of Windows with Powershell).

Comment: yes, I solved with powershell https://gist.github.com/juanpabloaj/40f9fa00964d566a8b0b

Answer (score 0):

Two tools, that can do exactly what you need.

1.[**TheFolderSpy**](http://venussoftcorporation.blogspot.in/2010/05/thefolderspy.html)-Freeware-[**Download link**](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/TheFolderSpy.shtml)

2.[**Watch 4 Folder**](http://leelusoft.blogspot.co.il/p/watch-4-folder-25.html)-pay version-[**Download link**](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Watch4Folder.shtml)

You can execute any *.exe file when a file/folder is modified, and "Watch 4 Folder" can execute a *.bat file also.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a batch file that will run in an infinite loop with, say, 1s delay between checks. The batch file would issue `DIR` command for target directory/file and redirect output to a temporary file. It could then issue a `COMP` command to compare with previous output of `DIR` and if output of COMP is not null custom action could be performed.